# Deploying in Worklight get alert: The file name, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

Last time I turned off my computer, worklight was working fine, everything was deploying and running properly. Today I turned on my computer, built my project, but when I went to open the worklight console I got a blank notepad window pop up, and an alert that said 'The filename, directory name or volume syntax is incorrect'. I haven't changed anything in my project since the last time, and I have no clue why this is happening. I just updated my worklight in case that helped but the problem still persists. Has anyone seen this before in worklight specifically? how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was really silly actually, yesterday I had opened an html file in notepad to edit it and set the default program to open html files as notepad. Since I didn't change it back, Eclipse tried to open the simulator path in notepad, I just had to change the default program back to firefox and everything worked fine

Comment: Good to see you fixed your issue. So as I pointed out in my response, the "Web Browser" used to open the console was "Notepad", which was the system's default.

Comment: I gave it an upvote: looks like there are so many reasons why this same issue can spawn, and I reinstalled java before realizing this was my exact same problem and i'm feeling exactly as silly as you did. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a problem in Worklight Studio at all. What web browser are you using? Is there any chance that your browser setup got corrupted somehow?

Comment: Hi Orlando, I'm using firefox right now. How could i check/fix that?

Comment: Do you use right click -> Open Worklight Console to reach Worklight Console? If so, you can then edit the preference (Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser) and specify an external browser (i.e. your direct path to firefox).